# How to make ActivePivot post-processors partition aware?

Tags: parallel-processing, partitioning, activepivot

ActivePivot uses partitioning to improve parallelism and that speeds up query execution. However, when doing a query involving a post processed measure, I noticed that the evaluation of the post processor does not benefit from partitioning : parallelism has not been increased.

Is it possible to make the post-processors evaluation partition aware in order to make my queries faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, ActivePivot does take avantages of partitioning to enable multicore scalability, speed up queries and data management and make possible NUMA (Non-uniform memory access) optimization.

To make the post processor evaluation in parallel, you need to create a `AMapReducePostProcessor` on top of your post processor. It exists in the core product a simple implementation of this map-reduce post-processor: `SimpleDistributedPostProcessor`.

Let's suppose your post processor is defined as follows:

```
 <measures>
      <postProcessor name="PnL.MyPP" pluginKey="XXX" [...] />
 </measures>
```

Just add this new post processor:

```
<postProcessor name="PnL.MyDistributedPP" pluginKey="SIMPLE_DISTRIBUTED" underlyingMeasures="PnL.MyPP.DIST"/>
```

Note the underlyingMeasures attribute is equal to `PnL.MyPP.DIST`; the suffix **.DIST** is **mandatory**.

The evaluation of `PnL.MyDistributedPP` post processor will be performed on each partition in a distributed fashion and will end the aggregation with the`SUM` aggregation function. If you want to use an other aggregation function, you can simply change it in the xml post processor declaration.